# Validation on list of url in Java fo POJO?

Tags: java, list, validation, playframework, annotations

Is There any `annotaion` which can help me to validate the list of URL?

```
private List<String> images;
```

i need to validate the size and valid url.
i don't want that user enters a long string in the name of url.

Comment: I don't think you have this out of the box. You can for sure create a custom annotation and a custom validator for that annotation, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use java bean [validaton](http://beanvalidation.org/1.0/spec/) :

```
@Pattern(regexp="^[_A-Za-z0-9-\\+]+(\\.[_A-Za-z0-9-]+)*@[A-Za-z0-9-]+(\\.[A-Za-z0-9]+)*(\\.[A-Za-z]{2,})$")
@Size(max=25)
@Valid
private List<String> images;
```

`@Valid` is used for collections.